# Will I be able to download the Linux version of a game on humble store, if currently only Windows version is available?

Tags: linux, humble-bundle

E.g., the game "Broforce" is out since Oct. 15, but against what the devs initially claimed, only Windows/OSX versions are out and a Linux port is do be released in the future. So, if I buy the game now via humble store, will I be able to also download the Linux version/binary when it finally arrives (without another purchase, of course)?

Comment: **Edit**: I'm referring to the DRM-free (stand-alone) version only, not Steam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I bught the Broforce game to test it. You dont have to wait. You can shoose the operating system which you want the game on. If the game will be released for Linux they will add the Operating system there.

You can also redeem it on Steam if you are not sure.

[image]